# How to run a Chrome Browser with Selenium in aws lambda (java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, google-chrome-headless

I have scenario where I want to run 100s of UI testcases via sidefile or java using selenium. To address above problem , I deployed  [selenium grid(hub and node) on kubernetes with autoscaling](https://sahajamit.medium.com/spinning-up-your-own-scalable-selenium-grid-in-kubernetes-part-1-e4017bac68f4). The deployment works fine but have some limitations I think.

1. Needs one hub and node continuously running even when you are not using it.
2. As all testcases runs in same cluster, it causes cluster to slow down.

To overcome this, I think we can use aws lambda and scale up and down according to the need. I tried going through some docs, and my understanding is this.

1. To Deploy selenium in aws lambda, I will need to make deploy a layer with selenium, chormedrive, chrome(headless) and java combined.
   How can I achive the above thing. I tried searching answer but most of them are for selenium with python env. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can find some nice documentation on how to create Java lambda layers here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html - Although IMHO switching from kubernetes to lambda seems a bit extreme, I'd rather look into ECS Fargate, which would also tackle your pain points, but you could reuse your docker containers. Lambda layers have other downsides like 250MB file size limit that you might hit...

Comment: There are multiple companies that do this for a living.  Is it worth recreating what they do?  They scale well and support multiple browsers and languages.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to figure this out myself, and wrote it all up at https://github.com/starkos/chromium-lambda-layer. See **Releases** for the layer's `.zip` file, ready for upload to AWS.

To make the image, you "just" need to:

1. Grab the latest `*-layer.zip` release from [@Sparticuz/chromium](https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium). Unpack it, then find the compressed binaries at `nodejs/node_modules/@sparticuz/chromium/bin/`.
2. Copy `chromium.br` to the layer's root folder. Decompress `aws.tar.br` and `swiftshader.tar.br` using [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) and move the library files and `vk_swiftshader_icd` to the layer's `lib/` folder.
3. Deploy a Linux64 [AWS Lambda container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) to a Docker container. Copy out these files from `/usr/lib64` and place them in the layer's `lib/` folder: `libglib-2.0.so.0`, `libXau.so.6`, `libxcb.so.1`
4. Grab the [Linux64 Chrome Web Driver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) corresponding the version of Chromium downloaded above. Use Brotli to compress the `chromedriver` executable; copy `chromedriver.br` to the layer's root folder next to `chromium.br`.

Here's the Java code to use the layer contents:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.brotli.BrotliCompressorInputStream;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class AwsChromium
{
    private AwsChromium()
    {}


    /**
     * Decompress a Brotli archive containing a single file.
     * @param archive The location of the archive.
     * @param destination Where to place the decompressed file.
     */
    private static void decompressFile(Path archive, File destination)
    {
        try (var inputStream = new BrotliCompressorInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                Files.newInputStream(archive))))
        {
            try (var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination))
            {
                inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static ChromeDriver launch()
    {
        var chromiumFile = Path.of("/tmp/chromium").toFile();
        if (!chromiumFile.exists())
        {
            decompressFile(Path.of("/opt/chromium.br"), chromiumFile);
            if (!chromiumFile.setExecutable(true))
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to mark `chromium` as executable");
        }

        var driverFile = Path.of("/tmp/chromedriver").toFile();
        if (!driverFile.exists())
        {
            decompressFile(Path.of("/opt/chromedriver.br"), driverFile);
            if (!driverFile.setExecutable(true))
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to mark `chromedriver` as executable");
        }

        var options = new ChromeOptions()
            .setBinary(chromiumFile)
            .addArguments("--headless=new")
            .addArguments("--no-sandbox")
            .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            .addArguments("--disable-gpu")
            .addArguments("--disable-dev-tools")
            .addArguments("--no-zygote")
            .addArguments("--single-process")
            .addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080")
            .addArguments("--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-user-data");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverFile.toString());

        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies you'll need to add to your project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.23.0'
    implementation 'org.brotli:dec:0.1.2'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.11.0'
}
```